# Deleteing Record with localstorage adapter in Emberjs

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

im using [LSA](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter) as my adapter.i can create record with this adapter but i dont know how to delete or update record with this adapter. when im using

```
deleteDragFromModel:function(item){
  var item = this.get('store').deleteRecord('axisModel',item);
  item.save();
}
```

im getting an error that say :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object axisModel has no method 'deleteRecord' ember-data.js:1388
```

if i `console.log(item)` the result is :

```
Class {name: "Cube1-1", caption: "Cube1-1", dimensionUniqueName: "NA", description: 
   "Cube1-1", levelUniqueName: "NA"…}
   __ember1379749368210: "ember743"
   __ember1379749368210_meta: Meta
  _super: undefined
  calculated: false
  caption: "Cube1-1"
  description: "Cube1-1"
  dimensionUniqueName: "NA"
  get uniqueName: function () {
  hierarchyUniqueName: "NA"
  levelUniqueName: "NA"
  name: "Cube1-1"
  set uniqueName: function (value) {
  toString: function () { return ret; }
  __proto__: Object
```

Comment: What version of ember-data are you using ? Seeing https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L246 it seems you can just pass the record, not the type. Or perhaps am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

Does the following not work?

```
deleteDragFromModel: function(item){
  item.deleteRecord();
  item.save();
}
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do it since Ember Data 1.0 beta 1.